# Google Analytics tag vs Container tag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tags

I am new to Google Tag Manager. I am reading a support document online (https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6102821?hl=en) and see the following:

`Google Tag Manager works via its own container tag that you place on all your website pages. The container tag replaces all other tags on your site, including tags from AdWords, Google Analytics, Floodlight, and 3rd party tags.`

This seems to be telling me GA tag is different from a container tag? I have an existing website that I know it is doing some GA things, but how can I tell if the tag is a GA tag, or a container tag that does GA? Does the `GTM-XXXXXX` portion indicates that it is a container tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GA snippet, or the block of code used to enable GA, is different from the GTM snippet.

The presence of "gtm.js", as shown in the GTM container below, or "GTM-XXXXX", as you've pointed out, indicates that you are most likely using GTM.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-ABC123"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-ABC123');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

The presence of "analytics.js", as shown in the snippet below

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

indicates that you are using GA directly.

You could also have both snippets of code on a page, which is not usually the best practise as everything you could do with the GA code, can be accomplished through GTM. Also note that just because you have the GTM container code on a page doesn't mean that you get instant tracking. You need to create tags in GTM in order to capture pageviews and events.